# XMLHttpRequest responses OK but still unable to fill div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a a simple index.html file with ajax in it. What I want to achieve is while I hover over (onmouseover) on a image the particular page1.html is loaded on div and when I get my mouse out of image the div needs to be cleared.

I get correct response (shown in response header in browser) but still unable to fill that data in div. Where am I doing mistake.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr;
function setContent(url){
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create request object

 xhr.onreadstatechange = stateChange; // register event handler
 xhr.open('GET', url, true); // prepare the request
 xhr.send(null); // send the request
}
function stateChange(){
 if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
  alert(xhr.responseText);
  document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
 }
}
function clearContent(){
 document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
img{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<img src="http://test.deitel.com/examples/jsfp/ajax/thumbs/jhtp7.jpg" onmouseover="setContent('page1.html');" onmouseout="clearContent()">
<div id="contentArea"></div>
```

Comment: is the alert shows the right html ?

Comment: Yes, the alert shows the response right.

Comment: There is an issue with your xhr because the code works http://jsfiddle.net/2zf0o7r8/7/

Comment: Thanks for replying @BipBip Putting text hard-coded works for me too. requesting page and displaying is the problem here brother.

Comment: that's why I'm telling you there is a problem with how you are doing the request and how the response is exploited